# AVD Google API's do not display available CPU/ABI

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded SDK tools and installed Google API's Intal x86 Atom image, however when I want to create my AVD it sais there is no system images installed for this target. BUT I have downloaded everything. I am using Ubuntu, on Windows machine same configuration works perfect, also for my colleagues same configuration works just fine.
If I select as target Android API 23, not Google API's it's okay, but I don't need Android API, since it's not working for me. I saw lots of reported defect, but none of them could help me.

Anyone has any idea that's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself today and I found a bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210223

To quote the solution:

> There seems to be some underlining refactoring which means the configuration now required is:
>
> Target = Android X.X - API Level XX
>
> CPU/ABI = Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

So, to create a new AVD with Google APIs support, just don't pick Google APIs as the Target. Pick generic Android with desired API level as the Target and then pick your desired Google APIs version in CPU/ABI. It works just fine, you will get Google Maps etc. on the AVD.

About that "but I don't need Android API, since it's not working for me" - I'm not sure what do you mean. You can't have Google APIs without using Android APIs, because Google APIs are running on Android device.